# Two developer License under same Apple ID

Tags: developer-program, license

we already have one developer license. Now we want to buy one more developer license. Is it possible under the same AppleID? We want to buy one more license under the same company name , same apple Id, basically apple ID(having agent role) is legal owner. So under same apple id wanted to buy 2nd license.

If no what are the alternate ways...

Please note  Entity Type: Company / Organization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible with the same Apple ID.

You can simply just create a new Apple ID, then join the developer program (as Individual), then your company can invite you to the team as a Admin or Member. Pick Admin to have access to the tools and profiles just like user #1.

[image: Invitation]

Every time you log in you will be asked if you want to be logged into your Individual account, or your company account you are apart of, just choose the company team.

**Note:** Your company account needs to be a entity type, 'Company / Organization'. This will not work for entity type 'Individual'.  As an 'Individual' count as 1, you can't have any other members.

Comment: basically under my company two teams will be working , team1 present team already have developer license. now for team two we want one license. so u are saying we have to create Team2 AppleID and invite. we can add them as admin role.??

Comment: I added an image to the answer. You can invite developers as admins to have equal rights as admin #1.

Comment: You will only have 1 team. But in this team there will be different developers. The current/main Admin #1 count as 1 member by default. If you signed up and got the invitation. You will have same rights as admin #1 but you are developer #2 in the SAME team ID.

Comment: what will be challenge we will be facing with already APP we have in iTunes  which uses 1st developer license and if we created 2nd license. can we publish with 2nd new license?

Comment: No.. You wont face issues. As long as admin #1 pays his developer program each year he wont have problems. Your 2nd account can only publish if he has the rights. Check in iTC -> Users and Roles. If you dont want them to add apps, give them less rights, if you want them to publish apps, give them all rights.

Comment: ok, but in general just wanted to confirm. can my company have two developer license offcourse with two different appleID, but under same company/Organization.       inshort two developer license's under same  'Company / Organisation'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41705/discussion-between-emotality-and-user2813740).